# Can not query struct field with hive (CDH 5.9.0)

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh

I just switch to CDH 5.9.0 (a full new install, not an upgrade, on a new cluster).
I have a table like this one (a bit more complex, but I reproduce with this example too):

```
CREATE TABLE `products`(`header` struct<PCODE:string, PNAME:string>)
PARTITIONED BY (`IMPORT_DATE' string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://myhost.com:8020/user/hive/warehouse/dbp/products'
TBLPROPERTIES ('transient_lastDdlTime'='1482160314')
```

If I do:

```
SELECT header FROM products;
```

==> The query is successful and return all products headers (in a JSON format)

But if I do:

```
SELECT header.PCODE FROM products;
```

==> It fails with the following stacktrace:

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
                at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
                ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
                ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
                ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:147)
                ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeFieldEvaluator.initialize(ExprNodeFieldEvaluator.java:61)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeFieldEvaluator.initialize(ExprNodeFieldEvaluator.java:53)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initEvaluators(Operator.java:954)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initEvaluatorsAndReturnStruct(Operator.java:980)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.initializeOp(SelectOperator.java:63)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:385)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:469)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:425)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.initializeOp(TableScanOperator.java:193)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:385)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.initializeOp(MapOperator.java:431)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:385)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:126)
                ... 22 more
```

On my old cluster (CDH 5.8.2), it works fine. 
Any idea?

[EDIT: I have downgraded all CDH 5.9.0 jars (/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars) to the CDH 5.8.2 ones and the query is successfull. there is maybe a regression in CDH 5.9.0...]

[EDIT 2: If the table is stored as TextFile ( 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'), the query runs successfuly.
We can think that the problem is linked with parquet.]

[Also posted on Cloudera forum: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-SQL-Apache-Hive/Can-not-query-struct-field-with-hive-CDH-5-9-0/m-p/48672#U48672 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I try a lot of things and I ended up with the followings:

```
-- Struct fieldnames in lowercase
CREATE TABLE `products`(`header` struct<pcode:string, pname:string>) STORED AS PARQUET;
```

Select results:

- `SELECT header.pcode FROM products` ==> **OK**
- `SELECT HEADER.pcode FROM products` ==> **OK**
- `SELECT header.PCODE FROM products` ==> **KO**
- `SELECT HEADER.PCODE FROM products` ==> **KO**

---

```
-- Struct fieldnames in UPPERCASE
CREATE TABLE `products`(`header` struct<PCODE:string, PNAME:string>) STORED AS PARQUET;
```

Select results:

- `SELECT header.pcode FROM products` ==> **KO**
- `SELECT HEADER.pcode FROM products` ==> **KO**
- `SELECT header.PCODE FROM products` ==> **KO**
- `SELECT HEADER.PCODE FROM products` ==> **KO**

**==> Avoid UPPERCASE in struct fieldnames with tables stored as PARQUET in CDH 5.9.0 (it worked in CDH 5.8.2)...**

Answer (score 0):

I'll fix this by lowering the case on the query elements. P.ex:

> SELECT header.pcode FROM products;

Comment: Thx but it doesn't work... but give me a clue :) I'll add an answer in a few minutes (that is: avoid UPPERCASE in struct fieldnames when using PARQUET and CDH 5.9.0).

Comment: It works onbly if the struct fieldnames are lowercased. But, if they are uppercasd, it always fail.